# Can't find dependent libraries in jar

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, jar, classpath

My java project uses javax.mail.jar. So, in netbeans, I created a new folder Libraries, copied the jar file there and added this in project properties. I added this folder to git and this runs fine on netbeans. But when I build the project with ant on another machine and run the project jar with

```
java -jar myproject.jar
```

I get the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/mail/MessagingException

I can see that myproject.jar contains the dependent library

```
$jar tf TakServer.jar
```

> Libraries/
>
> Libraries/javax.mail.jar
>
> ...

I'm not sure what is going wrong. Any idea how to get it to run?

Solution: As @Gimby pointed out, the jar files from Netbeans and ant build are different. Netbeans includes a lib/ folder containing all dependencies in dist/ folder and its MANIFEST.ML adds lib/ to classpath. The Libraries folder inside the main jar is not used at all.

Comment: If memory serves, I think that there should be a MANIFEST.xml file within your JAR. It should contain a list of your dependencies.

Comment: @nixgeek List all your JAR dependencies in `MANIFEST.xml`

Comment: How exactly did that jar end up inside the main jar? That's not how classpath loading works unless there is some underlying non-standard mechanism that extracts the dependencies first.

Comment: @npinti, Mr.Arjun There is only MANIFEST.MF but no MANIFEST.xml
Its contents are
"Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.3
Created-By: 1.7.0_85-b01 (Oracle Corporation)
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: tak.TakServer"

Comment: @Gimby In netbeans, there is an option "Copy Dependent Libraries" under packaging. I think because of this the dependency jar file is present in the main jar.

Comment: @nixgeek you say it works when built with netbeans and doesn't work when directly built with ant. So compare the binary output when you build it with Netbeans to what you get when you build with ANT; I'm pretty sure you'll find that when you build with Netbeans the javax.mail.jar library is not inside the application jar. Either that or Netbeans runs a specific ANT task to execute the application which does some work prior to running it.

Comment: @Gimby, you're right. Netbeans' MANIFEST contains the additional line "Class-Path: lib/javax.mail.jar" and it puts the dependent libraries in lib/ folder which ant build does not. Netbeans' jar also contains the dependent library inside the jar, but looks like it is not used at all. I wonder why it ended up there then. Anyway thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ClassPath in the manifest points to the filesystem outside the jar.
It it not possible to use jars inside jars

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html